# Singular value decomposition in R

Tags: r, svd

Following the [example of wikipedia's page on SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Example), I created the following matrix in R:

```
M <- matrix(0, 4, 5)
M[1, 1] <- 1
M[4, 2] <- 2
M[2, 3] <- 3
M[1, 5] <- 2
```

Computed the SVD from package `base`:

```
s <- svd(M)
```

Yet, `s$u` is a 4x4 matrix and `s$v` is a 5x4 matrix, whereas V should be a 5x5 matrix, as in Wikipedia's page (and other pages on the subject).

So, I'm a bit confused..

Comment: You need to continue reading on that page.

Comment: You're right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Reduced_SVDs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, R does not compute all the singular vectors. (Read the [doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/svd.html))

If you want to compute all of them, you can use `svd`'s arguments `nu` and `nv`.

E.g., in your case:

```
s = svd(M, nv = 5)
```

Check:

```
dim(s$v)
# [1] 5 5

s$u %*% cbind(diag(s$d), rep(0,4)) %*% t(s$v)
# You get M.
```

More generally, you can get all the singular vectors this way:

```
s = svd(M, nu = nrow(M), nv = ncol(M))
```

Comment: I read `nv <= min(n, p)` in the doc and I didn't think about trying `nv = 5`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge id Linear Algebra is somewhat rudimentary and dusty, but I think this one satisfies all the conditions of SVD. SVD is nothing but a factorization of the original matrix M in three matrices-- one diagonal matrix d , and two orthogonal matrices u and v, such that `M=udv'`
So the only restriction is that the number of rows is `v'` should be same as the number of columns in `u*d`

Here's the code  :

```
M <- matrix(0, 4, 5)
M[1, 1] <- 1
M[4, 2] <- 2
M[2, 3] <- 3
M[1, 5] <- 2
M

ans<- svd(M)
u<- ans$u
v<- ans$v
d<- ans$d
#u %*% I(u)
u %*% t(u) #Ok, is orthogonal 
v %*% t(v) #OK, is orthogonal
d1<- diag(d)
d1

(u%*% d1) %*% t(v) # is same as M 
u%*% (d1 %*% t(v)) # is same as M 
M
```

Comment: Shouldn't `v %*% t(v)` return an identity matrix?

Comment: You are right, Actually `v %*% t(v)` is not doing that,  but  `t(v) %*%v` returns a perfect Identity matrix. The question is why. __Can someone shed light on that?__

Comment: @R.S. `v` is not _the_ `v` from the real SVD, so it's not supposed to be orthogonal. (it's not even square)